# Can you specify the platform when running ionic serve?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-cli

I just updated @ionic/cli to v6.3.0 and noticed that running `ionic serve` displays the app with the iOS version of default component styles. In prior versions, the Android styles were applied. **Is there a way to specify which platform preview is served?**

Maybe something like `ionic serve --platform android`? I don't see anything like that in the [documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/commands/serve).

Related, but not what I'm looking for:

- I realize you can run `ionic serve --lab` to see side-by-side iOS/Android versions of the app. This method is sometimes useful, but also some drawbacks (mainly that you cannot resize the device to test different screen sizes).
- Changing `IonicModule.forRoot()` to `IonicModule.forRoot( { mode: 'md' } )` in `/src/app/app.module.ts` forces the Android platform styles, but this also forces the Android platform styles when you *build/compile for iOS*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well there's no way you can achieve this with ionic.

You can achieve this with Google Chrome.
In google chrome inspector tools (F12), You can click Toggle device toolbar (Ctrl+Shift+M) and then select any device from the menu. 
You will need to refresh after selecting the device to see the behavior.

Comment: That works great! I was thinking the platform was predetermined during the transpilation process. Apparently it's determined on page load by the user agent string? Also, the Ionic upgrade didn't have anything to do with this.

Comment: Yes, exactly Ionic determines it on page load and attach md or ios class.